# How to Stop Windows going below Task Manager / Panel on Fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, panel

I am running Fedora21 in a Oracle VM Virtual Box on Windows 7 (Pro, SP1). Although I have the task manager / panel settings to "always show", windows are going below it.

How can I get windows to not go below the task manager / panel?

[image: Application under task manager/panel]

Comment: You're using `kde4`, right? As I remember, the is panel configuration (or what ever it is called in kde's term) to set it not to overlay everything. Just go to the setting and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Oracle VirtualBox 5.0... solved it.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads